# Why does this regex work in JavaScript, but not C#?

Tags: c#, regex

#### Expression

```csharp
var regex = new Regex(@"{([A-z]*)(([^]|:)((\\:)|[^:])*?)(([^]|:)((\\:)|[^:])*?)}");
```

#### Breakdown

The expression is [crudely] designed to find tokens within an input, using the format: `{name[:pattern[:format]]}`, where the `pattern` and `format` are optional.

```
{
  ([A-z]*) // name
  (([^]|:)((\\:)|[^:])*?) // regex pattern
  (([^]|:)((\\:)|[^:])*?) // format
}
```

Additionally, the expression attempts to ignore escaped colons, thus allowing for strings such as `{Time:\d+\:\d+\:\d+:hh\:mm\:ss}`

#### Question

When testing on [RegExr.com](http://regexr.com/3gjm4), everything works *sufficiently*, however when attempting the same pattern in C#, the input fails to match, why?

*(Any advice for general improvements to the expression are very welcome too)*

Comment: Hi, because they are different a bit. According [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions): In .NET, regular expression patterns are defined by a special syntax or language, which is compatible with Perl 5. So, try debug your regex [here](https://regex101.com/), thery are Perl and Js regex implementations;

Comment: `[A-z]` matches more than letters.Every character that is between `Z` and `a` in ASCII table.

Comment: Can you maybe give two examples; one that works in both and one that fails in C#?

Comment: `[^]` isn’t valid in .NET regular expressions. (It should throw an exception, though, I think?)

Comment: See also [ECMA script regex option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#ECMAScript) in C#.

Comment: @Sach I haven't managed to find a successful pattern in C#, but you can check my link for a matching input in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ryan I suspected it would be something like that! It didn't throw an exception though, it's failing quietly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[^]` pattern is only valid in JavaScript where it matches a *not nothing*, i.e. any character (although in ES5, it does not match the chars from outside the BMP plane). In C#, it is easy to match any char with `.` and passing the `RegexOptions.Singleline`  modifier. However, in JS, the modifier is not supported, but you may match any char with `[\s\S]` workaround pattern.

So, the minimum change you need to make to make both compatible in both regex flavors is to change `([^]|:)` to `[\s\S]` because there is no need to use a `:`  as an alternative (since `[\s\S]` will already match a colon).

Also, do not use `[A-z]` as a shortcut to match ASCII letters. Either use `[a-zA-Z]` or `[a-z]` and pass a case insensitive modifier.

So, you might consider writing the expression as

```
{([A-Za-z]*)([\s\S]((\\:)|[^:])*?)([\s\S]((\\:)|[^:])*?)}
```

See a [.NET regex test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7B%28%5BA-Za-z%5D*%29%28%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D%28%28%5C%5C%3A%29%7C%5B%5E%3A%5D%29*%3F%29%28%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D%28%28%5C%5C%3A%29%7C%5B%5E%3A%5D%29*%3F%29%7D&i=%7BTime%3A%5Cd%2B%5C%3A%5Cd%2B%5C%3A%5Cd%2B%3Ahh%5C%5C%3Amm%5C%5C%3Ass%7D%0D%0A%7BTime%3A%5Cd%2B%5C%3A%5Cd%2B%5C%3A%5Cd%2B%7D) and a [JS regex test](https://regex101.com/r/7gfOTs/1).

Surely, there may be other enhancements here: remove redundant groups, add support for any escape sequences (not just escaped colons), etc., but it is out of the question scope.

Comment: Clearly explained, and very informative; much appreciated. As a follow up to your recommendation, I've removed redundant groups.